# Java Inheritance: Difference while inheriting super class members and variables

Tags: java, inheritance

I was going through Java inheritance and I tried the following code

```
class A {
    public int x = 1;

    public void print1() {
        System.out.println("Print from A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int x = 2;

    public void print1() {
        System.out.println("Print from B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public int x = 3;

    public void print1() {
        System.out.println("Print from C");
    }

    public static void main(String aa[]) {
        C c = new C();
        ((A) c).print1();
        System.out.println(c.x);    
        System.out.println(((A) c).x);          
    }
}
```

The output was

> Print from C
>      3
>      1

Now, my question is that I am able to access `class A member x` from `class C instance c` but why am I not able to access the `class A method print1()`. I know, if I want I can call `new A().print1();`. But, I want to access it from an instance of class C directly. So by overriding methods, are the top parent class methods lost in the bottom child class? However, the parent class members are retained (although hidden). Why so? And is there a way to call a method from class `A` in class `C` without creating an instance of `A`?

Comment: `C.print1()` will [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) `A.print1()` while `C.x` will [hide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) `A.x`. Those are different concepts.

Comment: They aren't "lost", they are just hidden from that classes API. You can only invoke these overriden methods from within original and subclasses. `public void print1(){
            super.print1();
            System.out.println("Print from C");
    }`

Comment: Do not redeclare x introducing a new field whose name hides the super.x. Instead assign to the one and only x in the child constructor. Method maps the signature, name and parameter types, to a single method reference. This mapping does not exist for fields.

Comment: add a method `getX() { return x; }` to each class and see what you get... ;)

Comment: @Thomas I know they are different concepts, but I want to know how to access a method of top parent class in a child class

Comment: @vikingsteve getX() will be overriden and it will always return the value of x of the type of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

### What's happening here?

When you say `((A)c).print1();`, JVM knows that actual the instance, on which it needs to call is `print1()` is of type `C` hence class `C`'s `print1()` version is executed.

But when you type `((A)c).x`, you are referring to state, not behavior and that too using reference of type `A`. Which version of `x` will be picked up, is decided at compile time as compiler knows what is the type reference (In this case `A`). That is why you see `A`'s state.

This statement from [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) might also be interesting for you:

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the
>   superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are
>   different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be
>   referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed
>   through super, which is covered in the next section. Generally
>   speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult
>   to read.

---

### Why is it this way?

Answer to your questions:

**Question 1:**

> my question is that I am able to access class A member x from class C
>   instance c

About variable `x`, since it is declared as `public`, no business validation can be applied on that. Moreover, the developer who's declaring it as `public`, is aware that concept of encapsulation can't be applied now (which is obviously not recommended). So there is no harm in allowing access to parent's state using child instance. Therefore, by using `((A)c).x`, you can access `x` from class `A`.

**Question 2:**

> However, the parent class members are retained (although hidden). Why
>   so?

It's because Java does not allow you to use `super.super.super..` arbitrarily to access any parent's behavior in the inheritance hierarchy. And the reasoning behind it is to preserve encapsulation. You can only access behavior of the immediate parent class using `super` keyword but not beyond that.

To explain it more, let's say you have implementation of class `B` like:

```
class B extends A {
    public int x = 2;

    public void print1() {
        if(x >= 2) {
            System.out.println("Print from B");
        }
    }
}
```

Now if `super.super` was allowed, you can easily bypass validation in `print1()` method of class `B` and can invoke `A`'s print1() method from the instance of class `C`.

**Question 3:**

> However, the parent class members are retained (although hidden). Why
>   so?

As, mentioned earlier, to retain encapsulation.

**Question 4:**

> And is there a way to call a method from class A in class C without
>   creating an instance of A?

So there is no way to access `print1()` from `A` using `C`'s instance.

Comment: Okay.. What confuses me right now is that from class C I can still access the method (behaviour) of immediate parent class B using super. But I cannot access the behaviour of A inside C?

Comment: Yes, that you can not do. using `super.super` from class `C` will result in compilation error. By the way that is logical as well, if you want `A`'s behavior (not `B`'s behavior) from `C` then obviously class `C` is in wrong inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @AniketPaul My updated response might answer your queries.

Comment: Yes. Pretty much clears my doubt. Can you suggest a workaround to my last question? I was thinking of defining a new method `final public static printA()` in class A and write the logic in that. And call `printA()` inside method `print1()`. That way `print1()` can be overridden but I would still have its logic safe in `printA()` . I haven't tried it yet. But do you think this a good approach?

Comment: I can not suggest you the right approach as I don't exactly know your problem. Beside, if you want to declare it `static` then you can not access any non-static member of `A`. 

One last suggestion, don't just use some hack to access a method of class `A`. If a method is related to instance make it instance method, otherwise if it pertains to the whole class then only make it static method. Use of `final` also needs some deep thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

When you override a function which already implemented in base(parent) class, when you call that function within the child class, automatically the class in the child will call so in your case when you call `print1()` of a C object:

```
C c = new C();
c.print1();
```

you will call the override function. However if in any part of your program you feel that you need to call the top parent class for any case (which cannot be fulfilled by `super`) then you should reconsider your design strategy; maybe you shouldn't override the `print1()` or even you shouldn't put `print1()` in the base class in the first place

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, only **methods** have the ability to be overriden. You cannot override a data member. This explains why you get the outputs.

`print1()` method of `A` is overriden in `C`, and `c` is an object of `C`. So, it will call the `print1()` method of `C`. On the other hand, the variable `x` is not overriden.

To call the superclass method, you can do:

```
super.print1();
```

Comment: print1() method of A is overriden in B. and if I call super.print1() from C then it will call the print1() method of class B

Comment: @AniketPaul No. FI you call `super.print1()` in `C`. Then it will call `print1()` of `B`. If you call it from `B`, then it will call the method of `A`.

Comment: As i mentioned , I want to access print1() of A inside C without creating a new instance of A inside C

Comment: @AniketPaul in that case you need to call the super method in `B.print1()` as well. After all, if `B` defines that `A.print1()` should be overridden and thus not be called by users of `B` instances then `C` can't change that behavior (think of `C` not knowing that `A.print1()` even exists ).

Answer (score 0):

Here , Same named  Instance Variable is used in all the Classes to confuse the compiler, but  you  should know that Only Member functions can be overridden not member variables.

So, All the three `x` will be stored separately in memory. but `public void print1()` will be overridden by its child class. So,

1. `((A)c).print1();` this piece of Code will Call the overridden method defined in class C. doesn't matter in which class you cast the Object of Class `C`.

But in Second Case `((A)c).x` will print the value from Class `A`.

2. `((A)c).x` :- this will reference to the variable `x` belongs to Class `A` not to Class `C`. because variables never overridden in Inheritence.

Comment: so you mean in the instance of class C, memory will be provided to all the members in the child and super classes (in this case three x's) but memory will be provided for only 1 method (in this case print1())

Comment: I am only say in context of variable. Yes. memory is allocated because if you know the work of constructor they actually initialize the variables and in each super sub class relationship consturctor must invoked using super() either internally or explicitly.

without instantiating how initializer will perform?? @AniketPaul

Answer (score 0):

((A)c).print1();   Actually it is similar to the c.print1(); .
It doesn't matter that you typecast it with Class A, it will still call print1() function of the Class C.